# How to implement MahApps.Metro Dialogs in vb.net User Control in WPF

Tags: vb.net, mahapps.metro

I'm using .NET 4.5 and MahApps.Metro in version 1.6.5 in a WPF project. If I got an error which should be displayed to the user I only have the MessageBox/MsgBox-things from the .net framework. Since I use the framwork of MahApps.Metro I want it to look alike. The mainproblem I have is that I use usercontrols instead of (main)windows and I **can't** change it.
Maybe I'm just too dumb and didn't saw the answer before - maybe it's on the hand - idk.

I feel like I tried every StackOverflow solution which were suggested, but they were all in c# and maybe they didn't work for vb.

Here's one example/thing I tried, but guess what - it's not working. Error Code is BC42358.

(saw the solution on stackoverflow, didn't know where exactly):

**MainWindow.xaml.vb**

```
   Public Async Function ShowMessageDialog(strTitle As String, strMessage As String) As Task
        Dim mdsMessageDialogSettings = New MetroDialogSettings With {.AffirmativeButtonText = "OK", .OwnerCanCloseWithDialog = False, .ColorScheme = Me.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme}

        Await Me.ShowMessageAsync(strTitle, strMessage, MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, mdsMessageDialogSettings)
    End Function
```

**UserControl.xaml.vb**

```
Public myMainWindow As MainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow

//some code

Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Try
            //do some stuff here
            myMainWindow.ShowMessageDialog("SUCCESS", "SUCCESSMESSAGE")
        Catch ex As Exception
            myMainWindow.ShowMessageDialog("ERROR", "ERRORMESSAGE")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

*I'm a newbie to programmimg so please be gentle - thx (:*